# Place div over other elements

Tags: css

I'm trying to place an icon over a div but the overlaying div is pushing the rest of the contents down. I'm stuck although it should be pretty easy. Please have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EESAc/1/) and let me know what I'm doing wrong (apart from using tables in the design!)

```
body{
 background-color: #666;   
}
.sizesbg {
    background-color:#fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
}
.soldicon {
    background: url("http://www.oroeora.gr/preowned/images/sold_curl_small.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    height: 155px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 170px;
    z-index: 2;
}
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="sizesbg">
        <div style="width:150px; overflow:hidden; max-height:140px; max-width:150px; min-height:100px;"> 
            <img src="http://www.carfolio.com/images/dbimages/zgas/manufacturers/id/843/bmw-logo.png" width="140" height="140">
        </div>
    </td>

    <td class="sizesbg">
        <div class="soldicon"></div>
        <div style="width:150px; overflow:hidden; max-height:140px; max-width:150px; min-height:100px;"> 
            <img src="http://mcurrent.name/atarihistory/warner_books_logo.gif" width="140" height="140">
        </div>
    </td>        
    <td class="sizesbg">
        <div style="width:150px; overflow:hidden; max-height:140px; max-width:150px; min-height:100px;"> 
            <img src="http://www.mindxstudio.com/images/mindxstudio-logo-icon.jpg" width="140" height="140">
        </div>
    </td>                
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `position:absolute;` on the divs, but of course the parent elements need to have `position:relative;` to stay in the right place

something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/EESAc/5/

**Edit:** 
This works well in Chrome ... but some other browsers had troubles (eg. Firefox), because for table elements position property is not defined, and you should use a block element instead ... so it works if you use another `div` around the images and set its position to relative. I added another quick fiddle for an idea:
http://jsfiddle.net/EESAc/9/

Comment: If using absolute positioning, remember the set the parent to be relatively positioned ;)

Comment: yes ... note the warning by Terry ... I made it more clear in the second jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EESAc/5/

Comment: This places all icons over the same image

Comment: I dont think so ... here I added another icon ... and it is over the third image ... it is positioned absolutely inside its parent element http://jsfiddle.net/EESAc/7/ , but as Terry said ... the parent needs to be positioned relative ... if this is not what you want than I don't understand the question completely.

Comment: http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/3473/clipid.jpg

Yes, that solves the problem, parent must be positioned relative and child positive. So the solution is both of your answers together. Hopwever, none of the fiddles display the right result.

Comment: Have a look at my screenshot and you will notice that it displays the icon only over the 1st image.

Comment: I see ... it worked well in chrome for me ... this is because you are using a table and td is not a block element like div ... to avoid this you can use a parent div around the image and icon that you position relative. I just put it in quickly into another fiddle just for an idea http://jsfiddle.net/EESAc/9/

Comment: Yes, that's what I did after you put me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I could help! Sorry for the confusion ... I guess I am just so much more used to using block elements than tables, that it did not hit me at first =)

Answer (score 1):

Give the class `.soldicon` a `position: absolute;` This way the element will be taken out of the document flow and won't affect the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following to your .soldicon css:

position:absolute;

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ssilas777/2YfnS/)**

Change your css to this:-

```
.soldicon {
    background: url("http://www.oroeora.gr/preowned/images/sold_curl_small.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 155px;
    left: -7;
    top: 0;
    width: 170px;
    z-index: 2;
    position:absolute; // Change to absolute positioning
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case (included popup element is bigger then including element) position: absolute; 
didn't work exactly how I needed it (scrolling bar was added onto including element and the included popup wasn't displayed entirely). So the solution was:

```
position: fixed;
```